# What is a correct way to handle writable M2M relationship in djangorestframework?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a many to many relationship between a Contact and a ContactGroup. One contact can belong to many groups, one group can contain multiple contacts.

I want to be able to display data like this, so I don't need to do multiple queries when showing names of groups where an user belongs.

```
GET
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Gandalf",
  "groups": [
     {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Lord of the rings"
     }
  ]
}
```

But if I update, I want to be able to update using ids or urls e.g.

```
POST
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Gandalf",
  "groups": [
     [2]
  ]
}
```

That would remove it from group 3 and put it to group 2 instead. I know I should write a [Writable nested serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers), but I have two questions:

1) I want to do this properly, what is supposed to be a good practice when I want to do this. Shall I send ids or the whole objects like

```
POST
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Gandalf",
  "groups": [
     {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Wizards"
     }
  ]
}
```

This one seems a bit weird to me as I need to send information that is not needed (name in this case).

2) If I can go with id/url principle, how shall I do this? In a custom `create/update` method, I can't have id validated, because a serializer points to a `GroupSerializer` and doesn't accept `int` type, it expects `GroupSerializer`, so accessing `validated_data.get('groups')` wouldn't get me ids, it would tell me `[{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]}]}`

I can write 2 serializers - one for create/update and one from displaying data. Do you think it's a correct way of doing this? Am I doing a right think in a first place? What do you think of this approach?

Answer (score 0):

For #1, you can leave the name as read only field in which case you'll have it for read and it'll be discarded for write operations.

For #2 as you want to remain consistent, your best take it to send:

```
POST
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Gandalf",
  "groups": [
    {"id": 2}
  ]
}
```

You really don't want to have a different style for read and write operations, really.